# Как сделать inline-кнопки "Вперед" и "Назад"? (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3

К примеру, у меня есть список товаров, представленный в виде Inline-кнопок, как можно реализовать кнопки "Вперед" и "Назад"?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужны доп. правки - прокомментируйте, предоставлю

Answer (score 1):

Создать кнопки "Далее" и столько же "назад", но в каждую из "далее" передавать разную callback_data, при переключении на след.страницу будут выводиться инлайн-кнопки второй страницы.

```
next_1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Далее', callback_data='next_1')

next_1.insert(btn_1)


back_1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)

btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back_1')

back_1.insert(btn_1)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text = "next_1")
async def ru_menu(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'след.страница', reply_markup=#здесь указываете инлайн_клавиатуру след.страницы)
    await callback.message.delete()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text = "back_1")
async def ru_menu(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, 'пред.страница', reply_markup=#здесь указываете инлайн_клавиатуру пред.страницы)
    await callback.message.delete()
```